# JDBC PreparedStatement default values on Insert (UCanAccess)

Tags: sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, default, ucanaccess

I was wondering how I can fetch the default values of newly inserted rows of MS Access via UCanAccess.

**Table: my_tbl**

```
Column   Type
-------+-----------------------
ID     | PrimaryKey, AutoNumber
Label  | Text
DT     | Date/Time, Default: Now()
```

**Code**

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO my_tbl (Label) VALUES (?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
st.setString(1, "my new label");

int insertResult = st.executeUpdate();
if(insertResult > 0) {
    ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();
    System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getInt(1));
}

//How do I get the generated value of DT
```

**Limitations**

I cannot use the keyword `DEFAULT` because UCanAccess throws an SQLException ([SO discussion about DEFAULT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749285/preparedstatement-how-specify-to-use-default-value-of-column)):

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: DEFAULT keyword cannot be used as column has no DEFAULT
```

Do you have another solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the generated value of DT

You will need to use the value returned by `rs.getInt(1)` to execute another SELECT query of the form

```sql
SELECT DT FROM my_tbl WHERE ID = ?
```

and then retrieve the value from the ResultSet produced by calling `executeQuery` for that query.