# PreparedStatement - set param to DEFAULT (keyword)

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, default

Although this question seems to be close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749285/preparedstatement-how-specify-to-use-default-value-of-column), it is actually different.

**Question**

Is there any way to specify `DEFAULT` value as a parameter in `JDBC`'s `PreparedStatement`?

**Use-case**

I'd like to have a single statement used for several inserts (or batch) into the table having some column defined as, say:

`updated    TIMESTAMP     NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP`.

Now, assume that I got a non-uniform set of entries to insert, some of them DO have a value for that column while others DOESN'T (effectively relying on the DB to generate it).

Instead of 'divide and conquer' pattern (which obviously may become exponentially complex if there are more columns like this), I'm looking to run the same `PreparedStatement` in the single batch, while specifying `DEFAULT` value for all those entries that DOESN'T have the required values.

Comment: Just set it to null.

Comment: Tried that and nope, DB dumbly attempts to insert NULL and fails on NOT NULL constraint (at least PostgreSQL with its official JDBC driver).

Comment: Not possible. The only way to use the default is to not include the column in the target list of the INSERT statement

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems that a statement of the @a_horse_with_no_name is straight forwardly to the point.

Gone over the [`PreparedStatement` Java 9 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) again and found no hints to anything even close to this.

I'm missing a functionality to set parameters to a DB functions/keywords like `DEFAULT`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` etc, but that's the state of `PreparedStatement` as of now.